# Karate Framework : #notnull and #present are not working in case response is empty

Tags: karate

My validation is to verify weather orgId appears in the response or not and that orgId should contain some value

The response that i am getting is 
Status code 200 and response body is empty.

Now I have below implementation

```
Then match $.orgId == '#present'
Then match $.orgId == '#notnull'
```

In this case the code passes, Ideally it should fail since response body is empty and orgId is not present in response.
My question is why is the code getting passed with `#present` and `#notnull` even if the response body is empty

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are definitely missing something. Try this in a fresh scenario and see it work. We are hard-coding `response` below, which is exactly equivalent to what happens at run-time, and by the way this is a great way for you to test assertions against different types of JSON (without making any HTTP calls):

```
* def response = {}
Then match $.orgId == '#present'
Then match $.orgId == '#notnull'
```

And this gives a failure as you expect:

```
assertion failed: path: $.orgId, actual: null, expected: '#present', reason: actual json-path does not exist
```

So if you still are stuck, follow this process please: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

EDIT: if your response is an empty string but you were expecting JSON, just do this and it will fail the test, refer type-conversion: https://github.com/intuit/karate#type-conversion

```
* json response = response
```

But as mentioned in the docs, you should always try to match "full JSON" so this should work:

```
* def response = ''
Then match $ contains { orgId: '#notnull' }
```

EDIT: this will be fixed in 0.9.4 https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/814

Comment: The scenario that i am talking about is little different .
The response is not {}
The response is actually empty

* def response = ''
Then match $.orgId == '#present'
Then match $.orgId == '#notnull'
This will not give a failure, Ideally it should fail

Comment: @ArchitGoel your question was not clear at all. anyway, see my edit.

Comment: I saw your edit and added as below 
* def response = ''
* json response = response
 Then match $.orgId == '#present'
 Then match $.orgId == '#notnull'

This gets failed by saying that cannot convert not a json string

Comment: This is just a work around, my question is why it should fail by saying cannot convert to a json string. It should ideally fail by saying orgId is not present or something like that. #notnull or #present is not even executed in this case

Comment: @ArchitGoel https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/814 - any questions ?

Comment: Thanks for raising this as a bug, will try to implement it.

Comment: @PeterThomas I know this question is old and was probably fixed on version 0.9.4, but I'm using version 0.9.5 and it's still happening when the body is []

Comment: @vianna77 and I'm sorry we are not supporting old versions